# Pagination links for taxonomy archive page 404 error on every page except first

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, pagination

I've created an taxonomy-regions.php template which displays all offers with the taxonomy.

```
$page = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

$args = array(
  'post_type'=>'praca',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 12,
  'paged' =>  $page,
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms'   =>get_query_var('regions' )
      )
  )
);
$offers = new WP_Query( $args );
```

On the bottom there's a pagination function

```
<div  class='pagination'>
       <?php $big = 999999999;  echo str_replace('paged', 'page', paginate_links( array(
                  'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                  'format' => 'paged=%#%',
                  'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('page') ),
                  'total' => $offers->max_num_pages,
                  'prev_text'          => '<span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-left-alt"></span>'.__('Previous'),
                  'next_text'          => __('Next').'<span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-right-alt"></span>',
                ) ));
      ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

Without the permalinks turned on the pagination works in the address bar there's

```
?regions=region_name&page=2
```

With permalinks turned on and on the second page, the structure looks

```
region/region_name/page/2
```

What am I missing?

This is what worked for me after some test and flushing rewrite rules, hope someone finds this helpful

```
add_action( 'init', 'region_rewrite' );
function region_rewrite()
{
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var( 'section' );

    add_rewrite_rule(
      '^praca/region/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)/?',
      'index.php?regions=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
      'top'
    );
}
```

Comment: It may be the issue of "endpoints". If I am not wrong you have register end-points to make it work. Please refer to this tutorial for understanding endpoint registration in WordPress.

https://www.pmg.com/blog/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api/

Comment: Please use search. This question has been asked and answered here many times.

Comment: do you think I haven't? none of those solutions provided worked out for me :/

Comment: If you have, then you should show what you've tried. `pre_get_posts` is the correct solution in this case.